# Unable to find project template in phonegap download

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cross-platform

I have downloaded phonegap 2.9.1 zip . But  I could not find the CordovaWP8App_2_3_0_Full.zip or CordovaWP8App_2_3_0_Standalone.zip  in this download. But I could find these files in 2.3.0. Should I use 2.3.0 Or 2.9.1. ?

If I need to 2.9.1 , what I have to do more .?

Please guide me on this to start developing app for windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your cordova project using terminal instead find project template for windows phone 8.

Install cordova using NPM

```
npm install cordova
```

create project using cordova command

```
cd C:\SANDBOX

cordova create your-project-name
```

add windows mobile platform

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

build project

```
cordova build wp8
```

done